# Interwoven Teamsite to create Resx files

Tags: teamsite, autonomy, interwoven

I have Interwoven Teamsite 7.3.x. We have some simple DCTs that current create DCRs in the standard XML format. Would it be possible to configure so that the DCRs are created to the XML schema required by ASP.Net Resx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following datacapture.cfg worked for me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
```

Form used to capture data for the MCA resx files

```
    <root-container name="root" location="root">
        <container location="resheader" name="resheader1">
            <item name="resmimetypeattrib" pathid="@name">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        resmimetype
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name="resimetypevalue" pathid="value">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        text/microsoft-resx
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
        </container>
        <container location="resheader" name="resheader2">
            <item name="versionattrib" pathid="@name">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        version
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name="versionvalue" pathid="value">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        2.0
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
        </container>
        <container location="resheader" name="resheader3">
            <item name="readerattrib" pathid="@name">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        reader
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name="readervalue" pathid="value">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
        </container>
        <container location="resheader" name="resheader4">
            <item name="writerattrib" pathid="@name">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        writer
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name="writervalue" pathid="value">
                <text>
                    <default>
                        System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
        </container>
        <container location="data" name="data">
            <label>Titles</label>
            <item name='lclMypointsResource1' pathid='@name'>
                <text>
                    <default>
                        lclMypointsResource1.Text
                    </default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name='xml:p' pathid='@xml:space'>
                <text>
                    <default>preserve</default>
                </text>
            </item>
            <item name="value" pathid="value">
                <label>My points</label>
                <description>Text that should appear in the points control</description>
                <text />
            </item>
        </container>
    </root-container>

    <script>
        <!-- get the item and set readonly in FormAP -->

        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/resheader1");
        item.setVisible(false);

        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/resheader2");
        item.setVisible(false);

        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/resheader3");
        item.setVisible(false);

        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/resheader4");
        item.setVisible(false);

        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/data/lclMypointsResource1");
        item.setVisible(false);
        var item=IWDatacapture.getItem("root/data/xml:p");
        item.setVisible(false);

    </script>

</ruleset>
```